# Failing applying jquery slice method over siblings tr (table rows)

Tags: javascript, jquery, visibility, slice

The following code it is auto-explained:

HTML:

```
<table cellspacing="1" class="CRMP_WP_QUICKADS_PLUGIN">
    <tr id="CRMP_WP_QUICKADS_tr_in_content">
        <td>
            <table>
                <tr>
                    <td>
                        <input type="radio" name="in_content" value="1">
                    </td>
                    <td>
                        Enabled
                    </td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td>
                        <input type="radio" name="in_content" value="0">
                    </td>
                    <td>
                        Disabled
                    </td>
                </tr>
            </table>
        </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <th colspan="2">
            Hover Ads
        </th>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>
            ...
        </td>
    </tr>
...
</table>
```

javascript:

```
$("input[name='in_content']").click(function(){
    if ($(this).val()){
        $("#CRMP_WP_QUICKADS_tr_in_content").nextAll().slice(0,6).show();
    } else{
        $("#CRMP_WP_QUICKADS_tr_in_content").nextAll().slice(0,6).hide();
    }
});
```

The hide/show effect is not running.-

Comment: What error is reported? I think you'll have to enumerate the array that slice returns, you can't call show() on an array.

Comment: @jivings there is no error. just not works. but FYI: following code works: `$(this).closest('tr').nextAll().slice(0,13).fadeOut();` the only differences is that now I replace `$(this).closest('tr')` by `$("#CRMP_WP_QUICKADS_tr_in_content")`. to get the desired `tr` element.

Comment: I don't seem to have any problem hiding the elements: http://jsfiddle.net/s8uc6/1/ Perhaps the problem is elsewhere.

Comment: Yes, there is no problem with that. Question was edited with the solution, tahnks!

Comment: You should write your answer below and mark the question as solved.

Answer (score 1):

Does this work?

```
$("#CRMP_WP_QUICKADS_tr_in_content").nextAll()
   .slice(0,6)
   .each(function(index, element) {
       element.hide();
});
```

Comment: Thanks. No, does not works. Any way `element` must be `$(element)` to apply  `hide()`

Comment: The element is a jQuery element.

Comment: No, is not a jquery object! Without `$` I have this error: `element.show is not a function`

Answer (score 1):

```
// is not enough:

    if ($(this).val())

// it must be:

    if ($(this).val() == 1)
```